# (JS) How to get values from this

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can i get the **a**, **b** and **c** from **answers** and display them in **< ul >** like this.

A: Hyper Text Markup Language

B: Hyper Text Mark Language

C: Hyper Text Main Language

If is possible to do it with for loop then please tell me how.

```
var questions = [
  {
    question: "Co znamená zkratka HTML?",
    answers: {
      a: "Hyper Text Markup Language",
      b: "Hyper Text Mark Language",
      c: "Hyper Text Main Language"
    },
    correctAnswer: "a"
  },
  {
    question: "Co znamená zkratka www?",
    answers: {
      a: "Internetový prohlížeč",
      b: "Dokumenty",
      c: "Celosvětová informační pavučina"
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
  },
  {
    question: "Co znamená zkratka FTP?",
    answers: {
      a: "Protokol pro připojení k internetu",
      b: "Program pro čtení pošty",
      c: "Souborový transportní protokol"
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
  },
  {
    question: "Pro poštovní klienty na internetu se používá",
    answers: {
      a: "TCP protokol",
      b: "IP protokol",
      c: "POP3 protokol"
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
  },
  {
    question: "Co je ICQ?",
    answers: {
      a: "Program pro řízení přístupu k Internetu",
      b: "Program pro posílání krátkých textových zpráv přes Internet",
      c: "Program testující IQ"
    },
    correctAnswer: "b"
  }
];
```

Comment: Add to what? Get all the answers or only the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var options = ['a','b','c'];
questions.forEach((question) => {
   var liElement = document.createElement('li');
   options.forEach((option) => {
      var ul = document.createElement('ul');
      ul.innerHtml = question.answers[option];
      liElement.appendChild(ul);
   })
   document.body.appendChild(liElement);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `map`

```
questions.map( s => s.answers[ s.correctAnswer ] );
```

**Edit**

> I want to show only the answers not correctAnswer

```
questions.map( s => s.answers );
```

Comment: @Gygram Check the update... You need to mention the exact output format in your question itself!

Comment: I dont think this works, it shows this. [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: @Gygram off-course it does.. You still need to iterate these... You need to share the exact output format.

Comment: Edited the question, check it please.